# Best way to handle a synchronous call

Tags: lagom

Say your ReadProcessor needs to insert records using JDBC, or you need to integrate with a SOAP layer via a JAXWS call.

What is the best way to handle synchronous calls using Lagom asynchronous (by design) platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In contrast to vert.x, which provide [dedicated possibilities to handle blocking calls](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#blocking_code), Lagom seems not to provide such an integrated feature.

According to [their documentation](http://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/1.0.x/java/ES_CQRS.html#What-if-I-dont-want-to-use-Event-Sourcing-and-CQRS?) (exemplarily for JDBC), one has to create own handling mechanisms, which internally create threads to run on.

So, the answer would be "do it yourself": create executors, runnables/callables and play with Futures to create an own non-blocking wrapper around your blocking calls.